Random effect models: Understanding within, between and contextual effect
In my quest to better understand, and more effectively apply, random/fixed effects and clustered standard errors, I am struggeling with the terms "within", "between" and "contextual" effect.

As far as I understand, we can only apply random effect models if there is no contextual effect - as otherwise the random effect assumption does not hold. Is that correct? Does that also mean that in such cases the within and between effect are identical?

Looking at the following example:



Data: Pooled cross-sectional survey data, where individual
respondents are nested in countries and the survey is held multiple
times in each country over the years
Research question aims at finding out if a country-level
variable (e.g. GDP) affects how respondents answer a question about
life satisfaction
Effect of interest: The overall effect of
GDP on life satisfaction

Which effect am I interested in here: Within, between or contextual? And would such research require random effect models? Or are clustered standard errors sufficient?

„I am struggeling with the terms "within", "between" and "contextual" effect.“ I have been hanging around here for seven years and occasionally answered questions about mixed-effects models, but these definitions have never settled inside my brain. I guess that they might be terminology that is only used in particular fields.

What is 'the random effect assumption' that you are referring to?

As to your question about within, between, contextual, look at this model:
$Y_{ij} = b_{0j} + b_W(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_j) + b_B\bar{X}_j \qquad$ (1)
For simplicity, let us speak of people nested in countries. $Y_{ij}$ is the value of the dependent variable $Y$ for person $i$ in country $j$; $b_{0j}$ is the (random) intercept of country $j$; $X_{ij}$ is the value of $X$ for person $i$ in country $j$; $\bar{X}_j$ denotes the sample mean of predictor $X$ for country $j$.  By using the deviation from the "group" mean $(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_j)$ as a predictor, its effect $b_W$ has a special interpretation: it is called the  within (country) effect, because the deviation varies across people within a given country, whereas the mean of this deviation is zero for each country. Hence, $b_W$ deals with change in the dependent that is related to $X$ differences between people in the same country. The other predictor $\bar{X}_j$ only changes between countries, and has the same value for people from the same country. Hence, its effect $b_B$ expresses change in the dependent related to (average) $X$ differences between countries. Note that in order to estimate model (1) you first have to construct the deviation or within variable $(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_j)$ and also the between variable $\bar{X}_j$, before you can estimate model (1).
Now, look what happens if $b_W=b_B$, and both are denoted by $b_1$. We can then write:
$Y_{ij} = b_{0j} + b_1(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_j) + b_1\bar{X}_j = b_{0j} + b_1X_{ij} \qquad$ (2)
This shows that in the more "simple" model (2) with only the original variable $X_{ij}$ as predictor, its effect $b_1$ expresses both the within and the between effect, if these two are really equal. Hence, if we would know that the within and between effect are indeed equal, we would not have to construct the deviation or within variable $(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_j)$ and the between variable $\bar{X}_j$ first, we  could instead use the more simple model, with the original $X_{ij}$ variable as predictor. That is to say: if you use the simple model when actually $b_W \neq b_B$, then the estimated value of $b_1$ will lie somewhere between the values of $b_W$ and $b_B$ that you would find when you would estimate model (1). In that case, $b_1$ describes the change in the dependent which is related to changes in $X$ within countries as well as between countries. It depends on the situation if you are happy with such a "combined" interpretation or not. No general advice to give here. But suppose you have longitudinal data: 12 monthly observations $i$ taken from the same patients $j$. And say $X$ is a binary variable having value 0 for months in which the patient was waiting for some surgery treatment, and value 1 for the months after surgery took place. You would then most likely be interested in change in the dependent that is related to changing from "awaiting surgery" to "having received surgery" WITHIN patients (patients are then said to serve as their own control for unmeasured/unknown influences at the patient level).
Now to the contextual effect. Instead of (1) we can also write:
$Y_{ij} = b_{0j} + b_W(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_j) + b_B\bar{X}_j = 
b_{0j} + b_WX_{ij} +  b_B\bar{X} - b_W\bar{X}_j$
or
$Y_{ij} = b_{0j} + b_WX_{ij} + (b_B-b_W)\bar{X}_j $
or
$Y_{ij} = b_{0j} + b_WX_{ij} + b_{B-W}\bar{X}_j \qquad$ (3)
In model (3) the original $X_{ij}$ variable is used as predictor and also the between variable $\bar{X}_j$. The regression effect of $X_{ij}$ estimated by (3) is actually the within effect. Further, the effect $b_{B-W}$ of $\bar{X}_j$ estimated by (3) equals the difference of the between and the within effect. So (3) can be used to test $H_0: b_B=b_W$. Such hypothesis test could be useful if you would actually consider to use the simpler model (2) and like to know how plausible it is to interpret $b_1$ as both within and between effect.
But apart from this hypothesis test, model (3) has a very interesting interpretation for the effect $b_{B-W}$: given that two people have the same value of $X_{ij}$, then $b_{B-W}$ shows how much the dependent changes when the average $\bar{X}_j$ values of both their countries differ 1 unit. Or: it shows the change in the dependent caused only by the "context" or countries and not by the people being different in $X$ values. This is a useful interpretation, often preferred above the between effect interpretation, which is really different! Look at model (1) again: the between effect $b_B$ shows the "raw" change in the dependent related to change in $\bar{X}_j$, without keeping individual $X_{ij}$ values constant! We could also interpret the between effect as the effect on the aggregated level. This can be seen as follows, starting from model (1):
$Y_{ij} = b_{0j} + b_W(X_{ij} - \bar{X}_j) + b_B\bar{X}_j \qquad$
If we calculate the average $\bar{Y}_j$ based on (1) we get:
$\bar{Y}_j = b_{0j} + b_B\bar{X}_j \qquad$
or
$\bar{Y}_j = b_0 + b_B\bar{X}_j + u_{0j}\qquad$  (4)
Equation (4) can be seen as a regression equation of the country means of $Y$ on the country means of $X$; $b_0$ represents the intercept, equal to the mean of all countries' intercepts in (1); $u_{0j}$ is the error term denoting how far country $j$'s $\bar{Y}_j$ value deviates from the predicted value $b_0 + b_B\bar{X}_j$. Apparantly, the between effect $b_B$ can be interpreted as the effect of $X$ on $Y$ at the higher or country level. This is quite different from the context effect, which holds for two individuals which are equal in terms of their $X$ values.
Model (1) and (3) are very common in multilevel analysis. Model (1) is often called the within-between model. Statistician Paul Allison some time ago used to call it the "hybrid" model, because it can be used to estimate both within and between effects, as explained. I only mention this in response to your argument 1) to reassure you that random effect models are very often used in combination with the contextual effect.

Nice explanation (+1). Our answers broadly agree, but yours is better, so I hope the OP accepts it !

@Robert_Long I doubted to answer because your answer was so clear already. But that contextual detail made me answer finally. Thanks for your nice comment!

Thank you so much for this answer, incredibly helpful! Sorry it took me somewhat longer to reply to it.

One of the best answer! I am struggling for the last few days. Lucky! I found this.


Which effect am I interested in here: Within, between or contextual?

This may be a situation where terminology differs between subject domains. My understanding of "contextual effects" is the procedure of decomposing the "effect" of a variable into "within" and "between" components. This is done by mean-centring the variable within the group and including the group means as level-2 predictors. So you would create a new variable for the mean of each variable within each group/subject and then subtract this from the individual level values, and then also include the mean of each group in the model along with the offseted variables. So, the original variable is discarded and replaced by a "within" variable (the variable that has been offset to the group mean and therefore varies within groups/subjects, and a "between" variable, which is simply the group mean (and therefore varies only between groups/subjects).
I am not familiar with the package you are using (and please note that questions about software - including "how to" questions - are off topic here), but you can adopt this technique using many different packages in R that fit mixed effects (or multilevel) models - eg lme4, glmmTMB, GLMMadaptive, nlme, mmrm.
To address your specific questions:

As far as I understand, we can only apply random effect models if there is no contextual effect - as otherwise the random effect assumption does not hold. Is that correct?

That's not something that I recognise. This may be an issue of terminology.

Does that also mean that in such cases the within and between effect are identical?

The way I see it, if a variable varies only between groups/subjects then indeed the models would be the same.

Which effect am I interested in here: Within, between or contextual? And would such research require random effect models? Or are clustered standard errors sufficient?

You could use either. The crucial aspect is that when you have grouped data ie. observations grouped by subject, and/or grouped by time (for repeated measures) then observations will not be independent (an assumption that is rather important). This can be accounted for by fitting random intercepts for subjects (and potentially country, though from what I gathered from the question you seem to be interested in the fixed effect of country so in that case you wouldn't fit random intercepts for country, but if you do then subjects will be nested in countries so you would fit random intercepts for the interaction of subject an country).  Also, since you have repeated measures then you may need to account for serial dependence within groups, ie autocorrelation, which can be addressed by fitting random slopes for time, or explicitly modelling the residual error covariances with, for example, a AR1 model (or several other structures such as compound symmetry, Toeplitz, ante-dependence, and fully unstructured).
Regarding the question of between and within, well that depends on your research question(s). Provided that a variable varies within subjects, then you can decompose its effects into within and between as I described above. And as I said there, when a variable varies only between subjects/groups the two models would be the same.
Finally, regarding robust standard errors rather than random effects, that's certainly another valid approach you can take. Unfortunately I don't have a lot to say about how to decide whether to take this approach. I would start by examining the literature to see if there is a "standard" approach to this.
You might find the following threads useful:
Between- and within-person level effects when using multilevel modelling for longitudinal data in R
Beyond AR(1) as a covariance structure for mixed models with repeated measures

Thank you, this is also really helpful!
